# How do I restore quarantined files in Commodo Internet Security Premium 10?

Tags: firewall, comodo-firewall

Please note the version. I tried to restore them but failed to find such a function? How do I do that?

The comodo help pages does not help at all as it was on older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I restore a quarantined item to its original location?

The process is extremely simple

Step 1:

> To access the quarantine interface
>
> - Click 'Tasks' at the top left of the home interface
> - Open the 'Advanced Tasks' tab and choose 'View Quarantine'
>
> [image]

Step 2:

> Select the item(s) from the 'Quarantine' interface and click the 'Restore' button at the top.

[image]

Additionally:

> An option will be provided to add the file(s) to Exclusions list and if 'Yes' is opted, these files will not be scanned again.
>
> The file will be restored to its original location. If the restored item does not contain malware it will operate as usual. If it contains malware it will be flagged as a threat immediately if real-time scanning is enabled (or during the next scan if real time scanning is disabled). The file will not be flagged if it is on the 'Exclusions' list.

Source: [Commando Internet Security's Manual](https://help.comodo.com/topic-72-1-766-9049-Manage-Quarantined-Items.html)

Comment: The manual for Commando Internet Security appears to go in specific detail which is unusual for security software